# How can you pass a custom collection class from VB.NET to VB6?

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vb6

I have recently attempted to port a legacy VB6 application to .NET.  It's not a complete port however as I'm focusing solely on the application layer.  I'll still be consuming a handful of  VB6 COM components.

So far so good, but I recently hit a wall.

I need to pass a custom collection from .NET to VB6.  Is this possible?

The COM method I'm calling on the .NET side is expecting a generic object however the application blows up immediately with: InvalidCastException - Specified Cast Not Valid.

I've stumbled upon a few articles that hint on how to pass VB6 collections to .NET but not the other way around.  I've tried inheriting from / utilizing a few different collection types in .NET but all to no avail so far.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231995/accessing-net-collection-in-vb6 ?

Comment: @MarkJ I looked at that question and it does not appear to be a duplicate. There is a way to make VB6 believe that it's seeing a VBA.Collection and I described it in my answer. Works for C# as well.

Comment: Here is why the questions are different - I believe that @RyanMac wants to preserve the binary compatibility, and probably the binaries themselves, for the VB6 components he's talking to. The question and the answers for 6231995 appear to not desire to preserve compatibility.

Comment: @Markus - You're correct.  That's exactly what I was trying to do.  Attempting your implementation now, thank you.

Comment: @MarkJ Please undo the "marked as duplicate" for this question. "Accessing a .NET collection from VB6" is not the same question as "Creating a VBA.Collection with .NET".

Comment: @Markus OK you're probably right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the COM interface declaration implemented by your .NET collection class, set the DispId for the method that returns your enumerator to -4. Call that method "GetEnumerator".

On the other hand, if you're actually wanting to mock a VBA.Collection object, and not just support For Each in VB6, you can set a reference to the VBA type library in your VB.NET class library (assuming you're creating a class library) and implement _Collection in your VB.NET class.

```
<Guid("A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB")>
<ComDefaultInterface(GetType(_Collection))>
<ComVisible(False)>
Public Class VBACollection
   Implements _Collection
   .
   .
   .
End Class
```

Then just implement the _Collection interface. If VB.NET doesn't like the underscore in the interface name, you may need to escape it.

Comment: Still no dice.  It seems as if VB6 wants me to feed it VBA.Collection type but you can't instantiate that class in .NET (although you can consume it).

Comment: Ah, ok, so the VB6 methods are expecting a VBA.Collection? Or, are they accepting your custom collection type and then trying to use For Each?  (Because, that requires two different solutions.)

Comment: I have added a solution that mimics the VBA.Collection object. My original reference implements is C#, and I translated it to VB.NET, so I apologize if it's not 100%. (The concept is the same.)

Comment: @RyanMac This probably won't affect your testing, but I had an extra 9 in the middle part of that GUID. I have corrected the example.

Comment: I ended up creating a bridge class library in VB6 that I referenced from both sides but your solution did work and the ProcID/DispID reminder saved me countless hours of trying to figure out why it wouldn't let me iterate through the collection.  Thank you.